# How to prevent VS Code from adding space before self-closing JSX tag?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, format, jsx

I have this issue for a while. We have ESlint and it forbids us to add space before self-closing JSX-tag, but when I format .jsx file within VS Code it inserts it. How may I disable it?

There is screenshot with the problem:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Use `eslint-disable-next-line` or just `eslint-disable`?

Comment: Disabling the line to just get around this warning isn't good advice in my opinion, the rule is hopefully there for a reason, otherwise remove it from your linters config. What are you using to format your code? Just code or something like Prettier?

Comment: @JanP Just code. Also I can fix this with eslint command, but I would like to do it by default with VS Code.

Comment: I assume you have "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingJsxExpressionBraces": false  in your settings - that is the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no such formatting option within the `javascript.format` options. But you can always look into extensions for this kind of job.

A lot of people use [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) these days, but it is opinionated and there is no guarantee it will work well with all your ESLint options. It has an [ESLint integration](https://prettier.io/docs/en/eslint.html)n though, so maybe you want to have a look at this.

You can also have a look at [react-beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=taichi.react-beautify), which seems to have an option for this. But I am not familiar with this extension.

Answer (score 1):

Use language mode **javascriptreact**, instead of **javascript**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code Settings search for "prettier" Default Formatter and change it to Prettier ESLint (maybe you will need to install it i dont remember)

and checkout for eslint rule "react/jsx-tag-spacing"

[check out screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JffLK.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).